# search value by row column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(df1). each cell means row, column indexes:

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1,1 | 2,1 | 3,2 |
| 1 | 1,1 | 2,2 | 3,1 |

How to perform search by row, column within the following dataframe(df2)

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 10 | x |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 20 | y |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 30 | x |

for example 1,1 of df1 is 1, 2,1 is 3, 3,2 is 6.

Final output for 3,2 should be: 180, x: (6(which is df2 3rd row, 2nd column)*30(3rd row, 3rd column),x = 180, x)

Comment: can you explain `Final output for 3,2 should be: 180, x: (6(which is df2 3rd row, 2nd column)*30(3rd row, 3rd column),x = 180, x)` ?

Comment: I have to replace df1 values by new one using df2

Comment: please provide sample dummy data and perhaps sample output in a table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `index` and columns values to `range` starting by `1`, so possible select by splitted values converted to integers by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) elementwise by [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df22 = df2.rename(index = lambda x: x + 1)
          .set_axis(np.arange(1, len(df2.columns) + 1), inplace=False, axis=1)
f = lambda x: df22.loc[tuple(map(int, x.split(',')))]
df = df1.applymap(f)
print (df)
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   3   6
1   1   4   5
```